# Socket fails to bind (C with WinSock)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

This is supposed to bind a socket to a port on the local host and accept TCP connections. When I run it, I get my "Bind error" message. I used [this](http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/) tutorial (see the "Accept connection" section), and the only significant difference I can see between that and my code is the position of the server address and port member initializations, which shouldn't matter, as long as they come before the `bind()` call?

I added a new rule in Windows Firewall (on Windows 7) to allow TCP connections from this executable, on port 8888, but that doesn't seem to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c;

    printf("\nInitializing WinSock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
    printf("Failed. Error code: %d\n\n", WSAGetLastError());
    exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nInitialized.");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;


    if (s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
    printf("\nCould not create socket: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nSocket created.\n");

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
    printf("\nBind error.\n\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nSocket bound to port 8888.\n\n");
    listen(s, 3);

    printf("\nWaiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
    printf("\nAccept failed.\n\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nConnection accepted.");


    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `bind`? I'm pretty sure it tells you how to figure out why a call failed.

Comment: Try calling WSAGetLastError to find out a more descriptive error code than "failed".

Comment: Thanks. Apparently "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket." But immediately above the offending code, I successfully created a socket (I get "Socket created" on execution). I'm looking at other examples, and the SOCKET type seems to match that of the function's first parameter.

Comment: @Vale132 The results of a comparison are probably not a socket.

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```
if (s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Needs an additional set of parenthesis around the assignment:

```
if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

The `==` operator has a higher precedence then the `=` operator (see [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)), so your original statement implicitly acts as if you had written it like this instead:

```
if (s = (socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == INVALID_SOCKET))
```

If `socket()` succeeds, the comparison would evaluate to `false`, which then assigns `0` to `s` (since `SOCKET` is just an alias for `UINT_PTR`, assigning a boolean value to a `SOCKET` variable is allowed), and then `bind()` would fail with the `WSAENOTSOCK` error (if `socket()` fails, the comparison would evaluate to `true`, which would assign `1` to `s`, then the `if` would evaluate as true and your process would exit).

Personally, I dislike code that does assignments and comparisons in the same statement.  This would be clearer and safer:

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Also, don't forget to call `closesocket()` on `new_socket` after `accept()` succeeds.